# Using Cassandra as a "schemaless NoSQL database"

Tags: cassandra

I'm looking at using `Cassandra` for an enterprise web-site I'm working on, which could be used by up to 250 million users. Cassandra seems like an obvious choice because of the way it scales, although I was a little sad not to be able to use a schema-less database like Couch (for political reasons I won't go in to).

I've read that you can still use Cassandra like a schema-less database, using either a `super-colum`n or simply `serializing` objects in to normal columns. At the moment I'm using `.NET` for my front-end.

Are there any libraries out there already that help with using Cassandra in this way?

Has anyone done anything like this already using .NET? Any tips?

Any advice gratefully received!

Thanks,

Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Datomic is schemaless. Attributes are modeled and generic objects can be created, saved, queried with any combination of attributes.

http://www.datomic.com

http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html#cassandra